# Static members not initialized as expected

Tags: java, static, static-members

The following code simply subtracts a value (10 in this case, just for the demonstration) from the current year obtained by using the `java.util.Calendar` class.

```
public final class Test
{   
    private static final Test TEST = new Test();
    private static final int YEAR = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    private final int eval=YEAR - 10;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Evaluation "+TEST.eval);
    }
}
```

I expect this code to display 2003 (current year - 10) but instead, it displays `-10`. I assume the constant `YEAR` hasn't been initialized. Why does this happen in this case?

Comment: Try switching the order of the declarations of `TEST` and `YEAT`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman even though it'll solve his problem - this is a very very naughty way to behave :)

Comment: It's very very naughty to have this sort of ordering-dependent code in the first place, frankly.

Comment: @alfasin - The order had to be defined one way or the other, given that the above code creates an order dependency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you are initializing `Test` before you have initialized `YEAR` - meaning it will go to the (implicit) constructor and initialize `eval` to `YEAR-10` before `YEAR` has a value (so it defaults to 0).

As denoted in the comments, simply changing the order of YEAR and TEST in the initialization will do the trick.

Comment: Hi, considering the code snippet in the question a puzzle code, remembering the order of evaluation is a hateful/tedious task.

Answer (score 5):

Because it's not `static` - you have to create an object in order to use this field! (or change it to static)

Try:

```
public final class Test
{   
    private static final Test TEST = new Test();
    private static final int YEAR = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);    
    private final int eval=YEAR - 10;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        System.out.println("Evaluation "+t.eval);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is obvious but why doesn't it work with `TEST` as an instance member - `private static final Test TEST = new Test(); TEST.eval;`? Thanks.

Comment: @Tiny Because when TEST is being initialized, YEAT hasn't been initialized and so defaults to 0. Static fields are initialized in order they appear.

Comment: @Tiny like I said: either declare `eval` as static or create an instance and use it. You can't use a class level variable with instance level variable when the instance was not yet initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Make `eval` static and it will work. If you do not want it static, then do the computation in the main method.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the problem is in the order of the static fields.  But, you can avoid the ordering problem entirely by lazily initializing `TEST` using a method (like is done in the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)):

```
public final class Test
{   
    private static Test TEST = null;
    private static final Test getInstance() {
        if (TEST == null) {
            TEST = new Test();
        }
        return TEST;
    }

    private static final int YEAR = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    private final int eval=YEAR - 10;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Evaluation "+Test.getInstance().eval);
    }
}
```